# C - Marshaling/Unmarshaling Struct with htonl and ntohl

Tags: c, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling, memcpy

So I have a struct in c, and I need to send it over a UDP socket. The RPCmessage should be flattened into a byte array which is message.data. Then message.data is sent over the UDP socket.

```
typedef struct {
    enum {Request, Reply} messageType; /* same size as an unsigned int */
    unsigned int RPCId; /* unique identifier */
    unsigned int procedureId; /* e.g.(1,2,3,4) for (+, -, *, /) */
    int arg1; /* argument/return parameter */
    int arg2; /* argument/return parameter */
    /* each int (and unsigned int)is 4
    bytes */
} RPCmessage;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned char data[SIZE];
} Message;
```

I am far from proficient with c, so I am not sure how to flatten this into a byte array to be sent over the socket. I believe I need to use htonl() to marshal, and ntohl() to unmarshal. But I cannot get my memcpy to behave how I need it. Currently I am getting a  warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

```
void marshal(RPCmessage *rm, Message *message){
    memcpy(&message->data[0], (char *)htonl(rm->messageType), sizeof(rm->messageType));
    memcpy(&message->data[4], (char  *)htonl(rm->RPCId), sizeof(rm->RPCId));

    /* more marshaling follows for the other 4 members */
}
```

Hopefully its something simple? But then when that's solved, I'm sure I will have an issue with unmarshaling the byte array back into the RPCmessage struct. My guess is to do something like this... But then I don't have a clue how to get it back into host order with ntohl.

```
void unMarshal(RPCmessage *rm, Message *message){
    //here, I am assuming *message is the message received from the socket
    memcpy(rm->messageType, message->data[0], sizeof(rm->messageType));
    memcpy(rm->RPCId, message->data[4], sizeof(rm->RPCId));

    /*more unmarshaling...*/

}
```

I have been reading the man pages, but its not clicking. Pointers are a bit over my head currently and trying to understand them better. 
Thanks in advance for saving my life.

Comment: `(char *)htonl(rm->messageType)` Nooooo, `uint32_t some_temp_var = htonl(rm->messageType)` and then `memcpy( .... &some_temp_var, ...)`. Also `unsigned int` may have less then 32 bits, I suggest `uint32_t` or `uint_least32_t` or `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `htonl` function returns a value of type `uint32_t`.  It's not a pointer, so it doesn't make sense to cast it to one.  That's what the warning is telling you.

You need to store the result in a temp variable, then pass the address of the temp to `memcpy`:

```
uint32_t msgType = htonl(rm->messageType);
uint32_t rpcId = htonl(rm->RPCId);
memcpy(&message->data[0], &msgType, sizeof msgType);
memcpy(&message->data[4], &rpcId, sizeof rpcId);
```

By the way, kudos for performing a proper marshaling / unmarshaling of your data structure instead of attempting to take the address of the struct to send / receive it.

Comment: Beautiful! That removes the compile error, however every index of message.data is a null character.

Comment: @Nate That's a different problem that would require a new question.  Also, feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept this answer once the whole problem is resolved. Since I have a null string, I can't objectively know this is the correct answer. I hope that makes sense. I'll post a new question, once I can see the string is filled and I didn't have to alter your memcpy, I promise to accept your answer :)